# changing /etc/network/interfaces has no effect

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have read many posts that to change your PC between static and dhcp ip addressing you change your /etc/network/interfaces file and then restart the networking with:

`/etc/init.d/networking restart`

However when I do this, the restart seems to go ok, but (for example using a static address) I see that the ip address is unchanged (using `ifconfig eth0`).

However when I do this manually:

`sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.20 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

Then it works fine, but only if I remove the "auto eth0" line from the networking file, otherwise DHCP is used.

So it looks like the networking file is used, but I can't get it to do static ip addresses :(

Here is my networking file contents:

`#auto eth0   COMMENTED OUT
iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.3.21  (USING .21 HERE TO DISTINGUISH BETWEEN MANUAL AND NETWORKING)
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.3.0
 broadcast 192.168.3.255
 gateway 192.168.3.1`

Am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to use an IP address that is within the scope of your DHCP server?

Comment: You need to use the command `ifup eth0`

Comment: @duenni no, the IP address can be anything at all - it is for talking to some custom hardware that may have any ip address.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq ah, is that in the networking file after the `gateway 192.168.3.1` line?

Comment: No. On the command line, instead of /etc/init.d/networking restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in having edited out the line

```
       auto eth0
```

which instead must remain in place. You may also wish to add DNSes to make your network work: add to the eth0 stanza the line

```
       dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Notice the plural, nameserver**s**, and the lack of punctuation between the two nameservers. If you don't like Google's, you can pick any you like.

As to the difference between `service networking restart` and `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0`, there isn't any: the file `/etc/init.d/networking`, which is executed when the service networking is restarted, contains the lines:

```
       # Provides:          networking ifupdown
         ...........
        ifup $ifaces "$@"
```

and so on: in other words, `service networking restart` uses `ifup/ifdown`. Both usages are ok.

Comment: ah, so I thought the auto eth0 was the part that told it to do DHCP, so that is why I removed that when trying to use static IP address. So you are saying I still need that along with all the rest of the lines I entered? (don't need DNS's : )
Thanks

Comment: Also when I leave auto eth0 in, I can manually set the static IP address, but then about 10 seconds later, it gets changed back (I lose my address)

Comment: @code_fodder The fact that you `lose` your static IP address is very odd. Can you post the output of `ip addr show dev eth0` before losing the static IP, after it, and then post the output of `dmesg` in between? Also: the part that told it to do `dhcp` was the word `dhcp` placed instead of `static`.